# Using HttpPost in Java to log in?

Tags: java, redirect, authentication, http-post

I was looking for a solution to my problem all around but couldn't really find the exact one.

I try to access to website which first requires to login. I try to login using HttpPost in Java but the response is empty and the next HttpGet returns redirection link to login page. Instead of the empty response I should expect to receive the redirection link to some internal page as while using a browser, right?

I'm new to the protocols, connections etc and I will really appreciate some ideas about what can be wrong.

```
HttpPost authpost = new HttpPost("/login/");
List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit", "ok"));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", ske_username));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", ske_password));

try {
    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
    authpost.setEntity(formEntity);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(targetHost, authpost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));

} catch (IOException ex) {
...
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server side code doing the auth?  what is the behavior of the server code when it process your request?

Comment: Are you sure you have the parameter names correct?  Did you view the source of the login page to be sure?

Comment: No, I don't have any access to the server code.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure parameters are correct, I did check the page and its html code

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking the response to see if it returns cookies that you need to have set in your subsequent communications?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO your next step should be understanding better how authentication on that site works, at the request-response level. You can use a network sniffer (such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) and perform the login manually (from a browser). The sniffer will show you the full contents of the requests and the responses, and then you'll know what your code should be looking for. (Like [RHSeeger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749138/using-httppost-in-java-to-log-in/6749234#6749234), I suspect that the answer lies in HTTP headers, especially cookies.)

Answer (score 0):

if you set follow redirects of your connection to true:

```
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
```

then you will be automatically redirected and as the response you et the final page. If not, it means something is wrong with implementation of your connection. Maybe something is missign. Check what exactly you get in response (response code and header)